# Regex Cut Words nearest to Keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, extract, keyword

I'm trying to make a keyword extractor in javascript, but it will include some context as well. There are a lot of steps, but most of them are quite simple except including unimportant words next to the keywords in the paragraph. I want to cut out the two words on either side of the selected keyword, along with the keyword. For example, if I have the sentence

```
let sentence = 'I was walking down the street when, suddenly, the TV came on.'
```

And the keyword was `street`, I want to extract `down the street when suddenly` from the sentence. Ultimately I will remove all the stop words (like `the`), but currently I just want to extract all the words. I've been using regex to try and achieve this, but have been unsuccessful. Here's my code:

```
let removePunc = sentence.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,""); //Removes the commas and other puncuation that could interfere with my extraction
let removeSpace = removePunc.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");  //Removes additional whitespace that's not required
const regex = new RegExp('([^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s' + keyword + '\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+)', 'gs') //Here's where I was trying to get the two words on either side of the keyword, although it currently doesn't work
let keywordZone = regex.exec(removeSpace); //This is where the regex above should "cut out" the phrase I want
```

I'm not very good with regex and am a little confused on why this isn't functioning how it should, since it appears to work for specific examples on [this regex simulator.](https://regex101.com/)

If I try it now, it doesn't do anything. For example, the sentence `Lawmakers, flight attendants, passengers oppose TSA proposal to cut screening at airports first reported by CNN` and the keyword `proposal` don't do anything at all.

Thank you in advance for anyone's replies, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing punctuation, you can just split the sentence at every space and select the two elements before and after the word from that array:

```js
let sentence = 'I was walking down the street when, suddenly, the TV came on.'
let keyword = "street";


let removePunc = sentence.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,""); //Removes the commas and other puncuation that could interfere with my extraction

let wordArr = removePunc.split(" ");

let keyPos = wordArr.indexOf(keyword);

let newSentence = [wordArr[keyPos-2], wordArr[keyPos-1], wordArr[keyPos], wordArr[keyPos+1], wordArr[keyPos+2],].join(" ");

console.log(newSentence)
```

If you put that into a function you can easily test it on other strings too:

```js
function nearestFourWords(sentence, keyword) {
  let removePunc = sentence.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, ""); //Removes the commas and other puncuation that could interfere with my extraction

  let wordArr = removePunc.split(" ");

  let keyPos = wordArr.indexOf(keyword);

  let newSentence = [wordArr[keyPos - 2], wordArr[keyPos - 1], wordArr[keyPos], wordArr[keyPos + 1], wordArr[keyPos + 2], ].join(" ");

  return newSentence
}

test1 = ["Lawmakers, flight attendants, passengers oppose TSA proposal to cut screening at airports first reported by CNN", "proposal"];

console.log(nearestFourWords(test1[0], test1[1]));
```

If you later want to remove words like `the` simply add those lines in before the splitting!

Comment: Hey! Nice I could be of help! Be so kind and mark the question as answered if you feel like it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to use a regular expression, then here is a simple approach.

```js
const sentence = 'I was walking down the street when, suddenly, the TV came on.'
const keyword = 'street';
const regex = `\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+${keyword}\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+`;

console.log(sentence.match(regex));
```

Refactoring it into a function quickly shows a shortcoming though, namely if the keyword is within two words of the beginning or the end of the string the search will fail.

```js
const sentence = 'I was walking down the street when, suddenly, the TV came on.'

console.log({
  street: keywordSearch(sentence, 'street'),
  I: keywordSearch(sentence, 'I'),
  was: keywordSearch(sentence, 'was'),
  came: keywordSearch(sentence, 'came'),
  on: keywordSearch(sentence, 'on')
});

function keywordSearch(str, key) {
  const regex = `\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+${key}\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+`;
  
  return str.match(regex);
}
```

This can be mitigated by using optional groupings.

```js
const sentence = 'I was walking down the street when, suddenly, the TV came on.'

console.log({
  street: keywordSearch(sentence, 'street'),
  I: keywordSearch(sentence, 'I'),
  was: keywordSearch(sentence, 'was'),
  came: keywordSearch(sentence, 'came'),
  on: keywordSearch(sentence, 'on')
});

function keywordSearch(str, key) {
  const regex = `(?:\\w+\\W+|)(?:\\w+\\W+|)${key}(?:\\W+\\w+|)(?:\\W+\\w+|)`;
  
  return str.match(regex);
}
```

Hope this gets you on your way.